# how to open new page on clicking label inside scrollview in ios

Tags: ios

i have added uilabel on scroll view.i want when i click on label a new page open.i have enabled the user interaction of label. but whenever i click on label nothing happened.the code is not working.

```
-(void)showlabel
{
    y=self.frame.size.height;
    myscroll = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, (y*4.2)/100, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)];
    myscroll.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    myscroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.frame.size.width*2.5, self.frame.size.height*3.5);
    [myscroll setScrollEnabled:YES];
    [self addSubview:myscroll];
}

    reach=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake((x*172)/100,(y*3)/100,(x*18)/100,(y*6)/100)];
    reach.text=@"ReachUs|";
    reach.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    reach.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:13];
    reach.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;

    reach.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
    [myscroll addSubview:reach];
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add tap gesture recogniser for that label to detect the touches. Try out following code

```
let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "reachLabelTapped")
reach=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake((x*172)/100,(y*3)/100,(x*18)/100,(y*6)/100)];
reach.text=@"ReachUs|";
reach.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
reach.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:13];
reach.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
reach.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

func reachLabelTapped() {
    //write your code here to open up new page
}
```